# Unable to fix the width in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

It's the first time I'm using twitter bootstrap.

I wanted to limit the size to 940 px, and for that I used the span12 class.
But it doesn't seems to be working. Whole content is spread wide across the page.

What do I do to fix it ?

Here's the code :-

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">

                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find Your Mac</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "spread wide across the page."

Comment: This seems allright http://jsfiddle.net/E72uF/

Comment: @Andy897

Here's the link to replicate the problem :- http://www.robocorp.in/design/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

The `navbar` is fixed at the top of the page. Even though the `span12` has a `width:940px` since the `navbar` is affixed to the top, it takes 100% width.

To fix this apply the width to `.navbar-fixed-top` as below

```
.navbar-fixed-top{
    margin: 0 auto; //to align horizontally in center
    width: 940px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working. Live link :- http://www.robocorp.in/design/index2.html

Comment: I checked the link and when i inspect element i don't see the styles applied. Did you add the above style to the page?

Comment: Yes, it's applied. Please check here :- http://www.robocorp.in/design/css/main.css

Comment: Yes you are right, when i inspect element on the page i can see the `margin:0 auto` applied to the `.navbar-fixed-top` but i can't find the `width:940px;`. Can you try giving `!important` for the width?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to put a `<div class="container">`, a `<div class="row">`, and a a `<div class="span12">` inside the fixed navbar.  Since the navbar is `position: fixed;`, it's removed from the normal flow of the page.  You'll need to define the containment inside the navbar.  After that it hardly seems worth keeping it nested in the original ones, so may as well make them siblings.  So, like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="span12">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Find Your Mac</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <!-- page content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You may need to adjust the specific nesting, but this should fix the immediate issue.